# How do add image to System.Windows.Forms.ListBox?

Tags: c#, winforms, image, listbox, addition

I'm developing chatting program using C# and I manage nickname list using ListBox. But, client have nickname, and state (online, away)

So, in order to manage the state, I want to add image (online - green circle, away - red circle) to ListBox (it is my idea)

How can add image to ListBox? Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16):

You can't do that easily in the ListBox. And drawing them using Graphics is not easy at all.  I suggest using a `DataGridView` o `ListView` control instead.

Result:

[image]

**DataGridView**: There's a ColumnType called `DataGridViewImageColumn` that you can use to show your status icon.

```
public void FillDataGridView()
{
    //images
    var greenImg = Resources.green;
    var redImg = Resources.red;
    var yellowImg = Resources.yellow;

    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Vland", greenImg});
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"John", yellowImg });
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Paul", greenImg});
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"George", redImg});
    dataGridView1.Rows.Add(new object[] {"Ringo", redImg });
}
```

[How to: Display Images in Cells of the Windows Forms DataGridView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/2ab8kd75%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

**ListView:** can add items composed by text + image. If you use the ListView, you need to add an imageList component to your form (with your images in it) and call their `imageKey` value like shown in the example

```
public void fillListView()
{
    listView1.SmallImageList = imageList1;

    listView1.Items.Add("BombPenguin", "green");
    listView1.Items.Add("Vland", "yellow");
    listView1.Items.Add("John", "red");
    listView1.Items.Add("Paul", "green");
    listView1.Items.Add("Ringo", "red");
}
```

[How to: Display Icons for the Windows Forms ListView Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ka5fex%28VS.80%29.aspx)

Answer (score 2):

It's not directly supported. However, you can draw each item of the list manually using the [`DrawItem`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) event; this will allow you to include an image for each item, using `Graphics.DrawImage`.