# PictureBox in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I need a ListView with two columns: the first one is for picture(mark question as true or false with some picture), and the second one contains some text, for example "Question № 3".

Can I implement it with listview or is there any other tool to to that?

It should look like:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using a `ListView` or a `DataGridView`?

Since that what you are trying to archieve is actually not directly supported by using a `ListBox` (at least I didn't found anything specific) and therefore needs more attention to implement, I'd like to recommend you use one of the 2 controls above.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821143/how-do-add-image-to-system-windows-forms-listbox) for some snippets.

Comment: Sorry, I meant ListView. Just mistyped.

Comment: Well then you are good to go with the provided `ListView` snippet in the linked question.