# C# Images in a listbox

Tags: c#, listboxitem

I have created a stock market simulation program, the prices fluctuate every few seconds and I track if they've gone up or down. I want to display a green up arrow if the price goes up and a red down arrow if the price goes down.

The prices are stored in an array which populates a listbox using

```
stockListBox.Items.AddRange( stockValues );
```

Could I create an object such as

```
Object [] stockObject = { stockValue , outputIcon };
```

and populate my list box with these objects? Where stockValue would be the value of my stock and outputIcon would be the green arrow or the red arrow

Comment: You can create your own class. Look this [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/2091/ListBox-with-Icons)

Answer (score 2):

The Windows Forms Listbox Control doesn't support other types then string.
If you don't want to go for external Libraries I recomend to create a UserControl.

Comment: Could you please link me an article? The msdn documentation seems a bit dated

Comment: step by step with images
http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/jayendra/how-to-create-usercontrol-in-windows-form-application/

Comment: note that you do not have to create a extra project but you can also create the usercontrol in your main project

Answer (score 1):

If icons is good enough, you can use listview. The Windows Forms ListView control can display icons from three image lists. Here is [idea](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z4ka5fex(VS.80).aspx)

Here is [exemple](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20821776/2050745) how can you use instead of ListBox: `DataGridView` or `ListView`.