# Scrolling list with multiple objects

Tags: c#, winforms

I have been making a form to let the user save his progress. There are 6 virtual slots which contain different save files read from a folder. I want to have the same set up just with a scrollbar to let user scroll through save files, in case he has more than 6 made.

The set up is: picturebox which loads save file when clicked, label for file name and for file date, picturebox to delete the save file, and a panel underneath to save file when the slot is clicked.

Below is the code I use to load in 6 save files. (I will get the date by reading the save file start as it contains the date, but I have not done that part yet).

```
    private void loadsavestoscreen()
    {
        string filename;
        string extension;
        string locpath = @"C:\test";
        String[] allfiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(locpath, "*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
        int counter = 0;
        foreach (String file in allfiles)
        {
            if (counter == 6 || counter == allfiles.Length - 1)
            { labelcheck(); break; }
            if ((extension = Path.GetExtension(file)) == ".dat")
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
                //Console.WriteLine(filename);
                changelbl(counter, filename);
                counter++;
            }
        }
    }
```

'labelcheck' checks if the text is correct, if not it hides the label.

'lblchange' changes the name of the label on the correct slot.

My question is: How would I implement a scrollbar to allow the user to scroll through more save files when there is more than 6?

Here's a snippet of the form:[image: Save Form]

I am slightly new to programming so my apologies if I've made some obvious errors. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I want to be able to load as many save files as there are in save folder, and so I want to have a scroll bar to use it to scroll through all those save files, without changing the size of the form

Comment: use table layout control inside panel with scroll bars

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without a list object or a container this is not very easy to solve.

I suggest you to use a `DataGridView` or a `ListView` object. You can easily add your file entries as objects to these lists. They have an option `Scrollable`, which you can set true or false.

I would also create a class for that save file entries (storing label/image position and contents) and add them to your `DataGridView` or `ListView`.

If you want to know how to add images to those controls:
[How do add image to System.Windows.Forms.ListBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20821143/how-do-add-image-to-system-windows-forms-listbox)